# How do i exclude words under 8 characters length?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a program that read lines (words of a dictionary)
, and I want to exclude words that don't contain, for example, 8 characters minimum.

I tried to search on Google, but I didn't find it.

This is the kind of program I would like to do:

```
with open('words.txt', 'r') as f: 
    lines = f.read().split('\n')   
    lenght = 8
    #and now the part i struggle with
     If lenght under 8:
        exclude it
    else:
        print(goodword)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `len(line)` to find the length of the string.

```
with open('words.txt', 'r') as f: 
    lines = f.read().split('\n')   
length = 8
goodwords = [w for w in lines if len(w) >= length]

print(*goodwords, sep='\n')
```

The line `goodwords = [...` is a list comprehension that can be replaced with a standard `for loop`:

```
goodwords = [] # initiate your list
for word in lines: # evaluate each word
    if len(word) >= length: # word is accepted
        goodwords.append(word)
    # else:
        # no need for an else clause
        # in the event that word has less than 8 letters
        # the code will just continue with the next word
```

Comment: @lilnewbiecoder glad it worked,  you have the option of selecting as accepted answer and/or upvoting (when you have the rep), or you can wait for a better answer, it is totally your privilege as the author of the question

Comment: Richie, you might want to offer a simpler solution with explicit `for` loop.